# Real analysis MVT problem for twice differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a twice continuously differentiable function, with
$f (0) = f (1) = f'(0) = 0$. Then

1. $f''$ is the zero function.
2. $f''(0)$ is zero.
3. $f''(x) = 0$ for some $x \in (0, 1)$.
4. $f''$ never vanishes
   The question is which choice is correct in the above choices.I know 3 is correct.

   I could not find counter example for 2.

Comment: $f(x) = x^2-x^3$ shows $f'(1)$ need not be $0.$

Comment: Yes..you are right.then where is problem in my argument.Since f'(0)=0,means either there maxima or minima at 0 for f.the same value f(1) is giving.means there should be maxima or minima at 1 as well.which implies f'(1)=0.

Comment: @MadhuriAgarwal That the first derivative vanishes **doesn't necessarily mean** there's an extreme value. For example, with $\;f(x)=x^3\;,\;\;x=0\;$ .

Comment: @joanpemo Yes...got it ...thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint for proving $3$: apply MVT to $f$ on $[0,1]$ to find a $c \in (0,1)$ such that $f'(c)=0$, then apply MVT to $f'$ on $[0,c]$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\;f(0)=f(1)\;$ there's a point $\;c\in(0,1)\;$ such that $\;f'(c)=0\;$ . Again, since $\;f'(0)=f'(c)=0\;$ , there's a point $\;d\in(0,c)\;$ where $\;f''(d)=0\;$ . Fill in details now.